# How to read checkbox/radio value in freemarker?

Tags: alfresco, freemarker, alfresco-share

I'm working with share forms in alfresco and trying to read the values of ticked checkboxes and checked radio buttons form a form. I extended both the user creation and userprofile form with these input controls and so far I have been unsuccessful at reading the textual values of said controls. Below is a snippet of code:

```
  <div class="row">
    <span class="label"><input id="${el}-input-spokenEnglish" type="checkbox" name="spokenLanguages" value="${msg("label.anglais"!"")?html}" />&nbsp;${msg("label.anglais")}</span>
    <span class="label"><input id="${el}-input-spokenSpanish" type="checkbox" name="spokenLanguages" value="${msg("label.espagnol"!"")?html}" />&nbsp;${msg("label.espagnol")}</span>
    <span class="label"><input id="${el}-input-spokenGerman" type="checkbox" name="spokenLanguages" value="${msg("label.allemand"!"")?html}" />&nbsp;${msg("label.allemand")}</span>
    <span class="label"><input id="${el}-input-spokenChinese" type="checkbox" name="spokenLanguages" value="${msg("label.chinois"!"")?html}" />&nbsp;${msg("label.chinois")}</span>
    <br/>
        <span class="label">${msg("label.otherLanguages")} : </span>
        <span class="input"><input id="${el}-input-spokenLanguages" type="text" size="30" maxlength="256" value="" <@immutablefield field="spokenLanugages" /> /> </span>

 </div>
```

unfortunately I get nothing so far from whatever is returned and would gladly appreciate some insight into this.fre

Comment: How are you trying to read the values? Client side JS? CSS? Server side after the form is posted?

Comment: Can't you just get the DOM element for the input element you're after, then just read the checked value as normal? Shouldn't be anything Alfresco specific here, just regular html forms/js

Comment: Sorry not JS client side script. Server side after post. Apologies. I have been up all night.

Comment: can we quickly converse? if you have 2mins or so? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27455/freemarker-alfresco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at **userprofile.get.html.ftl**, you'll see the following snippet:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
   var userProfile = new Alfresco.UserProfile("${args.htmlid}").setOptions(
   {
```

This means it's triggering a client-side JS file from Alfresco, in this case **profile.js** (see the head file). So just adding some input fields isn't enough.
You need to extend the client-side JS file.

In the function onEditProfile it gets the Dom elements.

But that's just for showing the actual fiels 'after' it's saved.

In profile.js you'll see: `form.setSubmitAsJSON(true);` that you have a json object from which you can get your fields.

And in **userprofile.post.json.ftl** it does a loop on the user.properties:

```
for (var i=0; i<names.length(); i++)
      {
         var field = names.get(i);

         // look and set simple text input values
         var index = field.indexOf("-input-");
         if (index != -1)
         {
            user.properties[field.substring(index + 7)] = json.get(field);
         }
         // apply person description content field
         else if (field.indexOf("-text-biography") != -1)
         {
            user.properties["persondescription"] = json.get(field);
         }
      }
      user.save();
```

This probably means that you haven't extended the contentmodel of the **cm:person** object with your new properties.

Comment: THANK you for this. No I didn't need to extend the person object according to jpotts in  this post: http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/02/27/1555 This is what I adapted. Do I need to modify this to take into account multi-valued properties?

Comment: But did you create your own custom client-side JS like what Jeff Potts puts in his file? So you had to modify the user.profile.head.ftl in order to put your own js there. And to debug you can loop through the json to see if your props are posted through the form.

Comment: I was wondering were to accumulate the multiple options selected. Didn't realise it was with the script on the ftl page. Thanks. If it works I'll credit you with the answer

Comment: Do you know anyway of getting output from this json file? I am trying to debug what's being passed to the java object. console.log() doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: console.log() won't work in your Freemarker, because it's a server-side object. So you need to loop through the object, like <#list json?keys as k>
  ${k} => ${json[k]}
</#list>

Comment: I was thinking more in the userprofile.post.json.js. I've been trying to debug that all day.

Comment: have you tried logger.log(json) or json.toString()
Enable javascript debug through JMX or in the log4j. log4.org.alfresco.repo.scriptlogger or something like that :)